# QWebview - setBaseUrl doesn't work

Tags: qt4, qtwebkit

I want to render html from a QString in QWebView using

```
QWebView::setHtml( QString, QUrl );
```

The images should be loaded from a temporary directory c:/temp.
In html code the images are referred only by file-names, without path e.g.

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

I provide this path as the baseUrl with the 2nd parameter of setHtml, but the images are not rendered.
I've tried to refer the images with full path:

```
<img src="c:/temp/myimage.png">
```

and it works correctly - the image is displayed.

I've checked, whether the url is valid:

```
QUrl base = QUrl::fromUserInput("c:/temp");
    if (!base.isValid())
        return false;
```

and the URL is reported as valid.
What am I doing wrong here?

I'm working on Windows, with Qt 4.8.4

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
A right click on missing image symbol in QWebView reviled, that the image had not the address
**c:/temp/myimage.png** as I expected but **c:/myimage.png**. I've tried to set the baseUrl as **c:/temp/.** and now everything works!

Looks like QWebView interpreted baseUrl as a html-file, relative to which the images are located. In my point of view it doesn't make sense for `QWebView::setHtml` where the source comes from a string, and there is actually no html-file, only base-directory.